# Request Payload - optional sending of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Creating a new user in `request payload` I am sending`name, lastname, position, job, colorEye`. And how to do that `job, colorEye`, which are empty strings, are optional. If `job, colorEye` are empty then send only`name, lastname, position`. Is it possible to optionally send data in request payload? If `this.state.eye` is empty I send `name, lastname, position, and job`. When `this.state.job` is empty I send `name, lastname, position and colorEye`. When `this.state.job` and`this.state.colorEye` are empty, I send `name, lastname, position`. When `this.state.job` and `this.state.colorEye` have values I send `name, lastname, position, job, colorEye`.

Do it just like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      lastname: 'aaaaa',
      position: 'bbbbb',
      job: '',
      colorEye: ''
    };
  }

  createNewUser = () => {
    const {
      name,
      lastname,
      position,
      job,
      colorEye
    } = this.state;

    const newUser = {};

    if(job && colorEye) {
        const newUser= {
          name,
          lastname,
          position,
          job,
          colorEye
        };
    } else if(job) {
        const newUser= {
          name,
          lastname,
          position,
          job
        };
   } else if(colorEye) {
        const newUser= {
          name,
          lastname,
          position,
          colorEye
        };
   }

    this.addUser(newUser);
  }


  addUser = newUser=> {
    const url = 'api/v1/users';

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url,
      data: newUser,
      params
    })
      .then(res => {

      })
      .catch(error => {

      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the above code not working for you? I think it would be better you send all the parameters and let the server handle it. At the same time, if it is needed that you have to do it on the client, use a switch statement to make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, think about solving this problem on the server.

Otherwise you can use [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). I prepared a fiddle, look at https://jsfiddle.net/jdwkLctr/

```
function getClearedUser(user) {
  const clearedUser = Object.assign({}, user);

  if (clearedUser.job === "") {
      delete clearedUser.job;
  }

  if (clearedUser.colorEye === "") {
    delete clearedUser.colorEye;
  }

  return clearedUser;
}

const user = {
  name: 'Saveli',
  lastname: 'Tomac',
  position: 'JavaScript Developer',
  job: 'The best company in the world',
  colorEye: 'brown'
};

const userWithoutJob = {
  name: 'Saveli',
  lastname: 'Tomac',
  position: 'JavaScript Developer',
  job: '',
  colorEye: 'brown'
};

const userWithoutEyeColor = {
  name: 'Saveli',
  lastname: 'Tomac',
  position: 'JavaScript Developer',
  job: 'The best company in the world',
  colorEye: ''
};

const userWithoutEverything = {
  name: 'Saveli',
  lastname: 'Tomac',
  position: 'JavaScript Developer',
  job: '',
  colorEye: ''
};

console.log("User:", getClearedUser(user));
console.log("User without job:", getClearedUser(userWithoutJob));
console.log("User without eye color:", getClearedUser(userWithoutEyeColor));
console.log("User without everything:", getClearedUser(userWithoutEverything));
```

Also, you can filter [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) using custom function and create new object using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3zta4dmx/

```
function getClearedUser(user) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(user).filter(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === "name" || key === "lastname" || key === "position") {
        return true;
      }

      return value !== "";
    })
  );
}

const user = {
  name: 'Saveli',
  lastname: 'Tomac',
  position: 'JavaScript Developer',
  job: 'The best company in the world',
  colorEye: 'brown'
};

const userWithoutJob = {
  name: 'Saveli',
  lastname: 'Tomac',
  position: 'JavaScript Developer',
  job: '',
  colorEye: 'brown'
};

const userWithoutEyeColor = {
  name: 'Saveli',
  lastname: 'Tomac',
  position: 'JavaScript Developer',
  job: 'The best company in the world',
  colorEye: ''
};

const userWithoutEverything = {
  name: 'Saveli',
  lastname: 'Tomac',
  position: 'JavaScript Developer',
  job: '',
  colorEye: ''
};

console.log("User:", getClearedUser(user));
console.log("User without job:", getClearedUser(userWithoutJob));
console.log("User without eye color:", getClearedUser(userWithoutEyeColor));
console.log("User without everything:", getClearedUser(userWithoutEverything));
```

Answer (score 1):

I also found a solution myself, it was simple:

```
  createNewUser = () => {
    const {
      name,
      lastname,
      position,
      job,
      colorEye
    } = this.state;

    const newUser= {
      name,
      lastname,
      position,
      ...(job && { job: job }),
      ...(colorEye && { colorEye : colorEye })
    };


    this.addUser(newUser);
  }
```